# WebSocket connection failing on every StackExchange page

Tags: support, web-sockets

I'm using Chrome 25.0.1364.172 m and on every StackOverflow page I'm logging the following JavaScript console error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://sockets.ny.stackexchange.com/' failed:
    Unexpected response code: 502
```

[image: WebSocket connection error]

Comment: Working fine here. What are the results of [this test](http://websocketstest.com/) for you? All green?

Comment: All green apart from WebSockets port 80. I guess this is an issue on my end then!

Comment: Yeah, exactly like Geoff [just said](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172697/152859).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What this is telling you is that you're traffic is being intercepted by a proxy further up the chain.  Usually this is the result of using a mobile connection of some sort.  You can verify your web socket support here:

http://websocketstest.com/

If you see that web socket support is available on port 80 it will work properly.  If not sadly you're out of luck.

Comment: No way for you for a silent fallback though?

Comment: Just commented on @ShaWizDowArd's comment on the original question - no, port 80 isn't green for me. Looks like this is an issue on my end, sorry for any confusion!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Writing to the console is pretty "silent", that's where you want errors the user doesn't need to care about; displaying a big error banner on the page would be annoying

Comment: @Michael doesn't look like `console.write` in action, rather unhandled client side exceptions, plus no live updates as result. On browsers not supporting web sockets I'm almost sure I saw fallback to the old mechanism using plain AJAX.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd the standard heartbeat code when editing answers etc still exists; the rest isn't a case of "fallback" - the live updates is entirely *supplemental* to the standard UI. Nothing was moved exclusively to there - it was all new features.

Comment: @Marc what about inbox new items notification? I'm almost sure it worked in IE9 which doesn't support web sockets.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I am having the same problem for a quite while (In all browsers). It was not happening before. I think it started after installing some important softwares. How to make the proxy not to intercept the traffic? any link?