# Getting error from websocket failing

Tags: bug, status-norepro, web-sockets

Related: [WebSocket connection failing on every StackExchange page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172696/178816)

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://sockets.ny.stackexchange.com/' failed: Unexpected response code: 503
```

Also got this error while writing this question:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 409 (Conflict)
http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/0/editor-heartbeat/ask
```

However, the resolution there was it was on the OP's end because port 80 was not properly functioning. I believe this is an issue with the websocket itself because that post was only a few weeks ago, and my port 80 *is* properly functioning.

Here is the link to results from the test: http://websocketstest.com/result/215701

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: that MSO link is now broken for normal users.

Comment: @PeterMortensen: It was very localized and has been deleted. Will delete my comment.