# Please add specific close reasons to the review queue on Meta

Tags: feature-request, review, meta

The review queues on Meta provide the highest level close reason. If a user closes a question with the reason:

> The problem described here can no longer be reproduced. Changes to the system or to the circumstances affecting the asker have rendered it obsolete. If you encounter a similar problem, please post a new question.

which falls under the "off topic" section, but is also about the Stack Exchange network. The close reason shows up in review as:

> **off-topic:** This question does not appear to be about Stack Overflow or the software that powers the Stack Exchange network within the scope defined in the help center.

In the case of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176952/getting-error-from-websocket-failing), which just showed up in the queue, this is *extremely* confusing. The question is specifically about the Stack Exchange network, should be closed, **and should be closed *with the reason the original voter selected*, but *not* the reason the reviewer sees.**

Take a look [at the review itself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/close/18727). I'm sure Lance Roberts and Richard Tingle were well-meaning, **but they likely also read this the wrong way, as the question should clearly have been closed with the given reason.**

In order to figure out what the real close vote is, I would need to go through the menu and check, or go to the question and check.

This is somewhat related to the question about the misuse of "off topic" in review reasons, though I can't seem to find that question at the moment.

Could the close reasons displayed please be changed to match the actual close reason selected?

(Also, if this happens on all sites, please let me know so I can make this a generic question instead of a Meta-specific one.)

Comment: FYI the review shows the specific message once the question is on hold. This makes your question a bit confusing.

Comment: It's not only a meta issue. It's an issue everywhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show sub reasons in close review queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192634/show-sub-reasons-in-close-review-queue). Related: [Better flagging as off topic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188106/better-flagging-as-off-topic).

Comment: I definitely saw the off-topic reason, which I didn't feel it fell under.  I didn't realize it was changing thigs.