# Helpful flag count and flagging history shows wrong details

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags

Today I saw a terrible thing in my profile

[image]

I'm a Deputy badge holder but my profile is only showing 10 helpful flags.

What is happened to my flags?

The flagging history also looks so confusing, missing many flags.

Comment: I am not sure, it's a bug, it seems like that only

Comment: And this reduces the number of flags you can use per day. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184176/flags-are-broken-on-mso#comment562654_184176).

Comment: Related: [Flags are broken on MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184176/flags-are-broken-on-mso)

Comment: It is only counting the "custom" flag and "Spam/Offensive" flag.

Comment: @Rory it happens only in meta because the new mechanism is still not deployed to all sites... not sure it's a meta-meta issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With the reworking of close reasons and flags, the query picking the helpful/declined and the flagging summary was not taking account of closing.

It does now.

Comment: (waiting for rush of people checking their helpful flags count)

Comment: it seems good now

Comment: I can't check my inbox because of this [reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180605/an-error-occured-while-loading-whats-that)

Comment: @Azik - did you check the network traffic? Are there any blocked scripts? Are websockets going through?

Comment: I don't know about those technical things, pls assist me how to resolve that issue

Comment: @Azik - Without those "technical things", I can't help. In chrome, open the developer tools, go to the network tab and reload the page. Is there anything coming up with a 404 or 500 on the status?

Comment: `WebSocket connection to 'ws://sockets.ny.stackexchange.com/' failed: Unexpected response code: 502 ` message occurs, now what to do?. I know you are not here to help these type of issues, but give me one more step

Comment: @Azik - see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172697/140505

Comment: no-luck, port 80 is not green for me on websocket test

Comment: @Azik - Nothing we can do about it, unfortunately. Talk to your ISP.

Comment: Thanx for the details

Comment: :o My comment flags are showing! Woohoo! Was this a recent change or another bug?

Comment: @animuson - It was intentional. And recent.

Comment: @Oded: I also seem to be seeing other flags that are not mine in addition to *my* flags on certain posts. What is the [scheduledtaskinvalidated](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8Jsnc.jpg) dismiss reason?

Comment: @animuson - That shouldn't be there... But essentially, it means dismissed by a job (aka aged)

Comment: Flags can age out?  I thought they stayed in the queue until handled?

Comment: @MonicaCellio - Some flags and votes do age.

Comment: @animuson or Oded - Can you answer the question [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202515/why-was-my-flag-marked-scheduledtaskinvalidated)?