# Did the new Close Vote reasons just wipe out existing close votes?

Tags: support, review, vote-to-close

I had been watching a question that had a few close votes on it, and when I refreshed the page, the close votes were gone.

Then I went to the review tab, and found this:

[image]

*Whaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaah?*  I recall possibly reading that close votes wouldn't be backwards compatible, but did 55K+ questions just lose their close votes?

Comment: That was an easy way to clear out the review queue.

Comment: I cast two close votes on the same question because my first one vanished. Also my helpful flag count suddenly increased (cannot say by how much though), but that might be unrelated.

Comment: I just found [a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17307363/how-to-see-a-password-protected-post-in-a-blog#) that has five close votes, but is still open.  **Weirdness**.

Comment: Aaaand now it is closed.

Comment: @Chris - with six votes ;)  It's super-on-hold.

Comment: Creepy indeed. I'm still trying to figure out if I'm upset that the close queue is empty. I mean.... it is empty. Yay?

Comment: @Chris Maybe they should implement something similar to clean the flags

Comment: @Felix: The helpful flag count should have increased because all the old comment flags are now shown in history and should now have a status applied to them.

Comment: @animuson: Thanks! Was this mentioned somewhere explicitly?

Comment: @Felix: I had [asked Oded about it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184233/helpful-flag-count-and-flagging-history-shows-wrong-details/184275#comment563158_184275) when I noticed on Meta (only because I had recently flagged a comment here).

Comment: Oh damn. All 55.5k of them are back.

Comment: **YES!!!!!!!!!!!!1one!**

Comment: Hah, I downvoted myself by closing this, that's mildly amusing.

Comment: Hmmm, that's a little unfair. Meta could do with an exception for this thing... the whole "off-topic" part of too localized on MSO doesn't seem right somehow.

Comment: @LBT You no longer incur a downvote for having your question closed anymore...

Comment: @gparyani -- yeah, I know that, but back in June it did.  Thanks for the update, though.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This was a mistake - it has been corrected.

[image: 55.6K, baby]

Comment: The review limit has been reduced to 20?

Comment: That should correct itself as well.

Comment: At least we now know the answer to [When was the number of questions with close votes to review 0 on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183840/when-was-the-number-of-questions-with-close-votes-to-review-0-on-stack-overflow/)

Comment: you corrected it the other way 'round. Right way would be to clo... oops "put on hold" all these 55.whatever-K

Comment: Thanks for the surprise, and the update!

Comment: Define 'mistake' :)