# Flag count is missing from profile pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, flags

The part of the profile page that (if you've flagged anything) gives a total and a link to your flag history has gone missing:

[image: screencap]

Note in the screen capture that I am a moderator on that site, and trust me I've flagged posts.  I first noticed this absence in my user profile on Hermeneutics, where I am not a mod.  (I have the Deputy badge -- so, again, there are definitely flags.)

I am not seeing this with my profile here on MSO.

Firefox 18 and Chrome 16,0.912.77, Win XP.

Going directly to the flag-summary page (on Mi Yodeya) shows no flag activity.

Comment: My flag count is still showing on Stack Overflow but is missing on my DBA.SE profile.

Comment: Weirdness is running wild today...

Comment: My flag count is higher as it should be. Looks like comment flag are counted now which wasn't previously?

Comment: @juergend, did you steal my flags? :-)

Comment: And if you go directly to the flag history page?

Comment: @juergend: Yes, old comments were assigned a status. They also [appear in your history](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184233/helpful-flag-count-and-flagging-history-shows-wrong-details/184275#comment563158_184275) now.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd good idea.  The flag-summary page is as if I had no flags.  The problem appears to be deeper than the profile page.

Comment: The flag count is also missing on all four beta sites I checked.

Comment: Missing on: Mi Yodeya, Hermeneutics, ELU, Workplace, Wrtiers, BCG.  (I think those + MSO are all the sites on which I have Citizen Patrol, hence flags.)

Comment: Missing on Arqade.

Comment: Yep, all my flags are gone on Arqade. I flagged a few more things, and [it now says that I have three helpful flags total.](http://i.imgur.com/LgzP7qX.png)

Comment: I just flagged some things on Writers meta and it shows my flag count at 2 -- but I already had Citizen Patrol.  Looks like the records of our flags got flushed?

Comment: Yep, the entire stats on the tens of thousands of flags that have been casted on Arqade have gone.

Comment: Monica - looks like it. The upper limit for flags is re-set to 10 as well.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/U6lzD.jpg

Comment: @badp'skitten, same on Mi Yodeya; I just checked the list of most-flagged users and got nothin'.  Flag history from individual posts is gone too.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Flags are back now on Arqade

Comment: I've noticed [slightly different behavior](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7333/did-something-change-in-the-calculation-of-helpful-flags) on Arqade -  specifically, I seem to have picked up ~40 new Helpful Flags during the course of the day. (I haven't flagged anything today.)

Comment: They're back on Mi Yodeya now too.  @badp'skitten, can you ask your person to mark this status-complete?

Comment: @MonicaCellio My useless human has no diamond powers here.

Comment: @badp'skitten aw man, what are people *for*, then?  So, should I, um, flag this? :-)

Comment: @MonicaCellio Food, shelter and tummy rubbing, obviously.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We're rolling out a massive refactoring around flags, including how and where they're stored in the database.

The data required a backfill, which has just completed, so everything should be back to normal (or better!) (or worse :( ).

Just report bugs you notice - thank you!

Comment: Would an increase of 40 in my Helpful Flag count be considered a bug? Or has the calculation changed in some way?

Comment: I jumped from 45 to 99 as well.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz it's by-design.  Comment flags weren't being counted correctly.