# Why was my flag marked "scheduledtaskinvalidated"?

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, flag-history, aged-away

I know that there are three reasons with which a flag can be dismissed: helpful, declined, or disputed. However, I recently came across this fourth one:

[image: Flag marked "scheduledtaskinvalidated"]

It has been pointed out to me that this could be a bug. What causes flags to be dismissed with it, and when will this be fixed (if it is a bug)?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184233/helpful-flag-count-and-flagging-history-shows-wrong-details#comment563162_184275

Comment: @Bart I saw that, but I want more elaboration...

Comment: @Bart I agree with OP - this deserves full answer people could link to ;)

Comment: That's a bug in the flag history page, as Oded said in a comment on the other post it should not be there.

Comment: I removed the bounty; I don't want rep for my own bug.

Comment: @JarrodDixon And I always thought that the devs intentionally add bugs to claim the bounty ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a bug in the rendering of that specific flag type.

After a period of time, flags that are not acted upon by mods or other community members will get cleaned up automatically by [internal scheduled tasks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56614/what-happened-here-voted-to-close-4-days-ago-but-no-close-votes-today/97594#97594).  This prevents flags from accruing over time and allowing actions that the greater community in general doesn't want.

This cleanup process can also be triggered by review tasks that contradict a flag.  This is what occurred (erroneously*) in your specific case.

Next build will fix the display to read just that: *aged away*.

<sub>* I agreed with your flag - that question didn't belong on SO (or anywhere else), so I deleted it.  A [simple Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow%20api) would have provided its answer.</sub>

Comment: Can you also add a counter to the right side of the page for aged away flags?

Comment: I proposed an FAQ here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204327/when-are-flags-dismissed-as-aged-away

Comment: is is probably worth noting that [flags to close (except for migration) do not expire](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207180/165773) (as opposed to close votes) - which is not quite a good thing. Keeping a wide open door for tens thousands SO users to push the items into CV queue and keep them without limits makes any attempts to decrease queue size like peeing against the wind

Comment: Is this bug back? https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/admin/posts/2036/show-flags