# too many of your recent flags declined, but not in reality

Tags: support, flags

I was gonna flag a post for `reopen` but could because it show me this error:

[image: error]

but, look at my flag list:

[image: flag list]

[image]

**Note:** There are flags "waiting" for over a month until now. This is why I got so many on hold.

How can I fix this?

---

***Since 02-14-2014:***

- Declined + Disputed (*I'm counting Disputed as Declined because I have only 2 Declined*):     **6**
- Active: **14**
- Helpful: **13**

Comment: It isn't "too many"... it says "too many of your recent...".  there is a huge difference between the 2 statements.

Comment: You may be interested in the definition of the message.  You can review everything in [Shog's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405/182513)

Comment: @psubsee2003 sorry, I tough it was the same. I'll fix it. Can you explain how is this difference and how can I fix it? btw, I'm adding an img with the list (as you can see there are so many declined at all)

Comment: The answer is in the answer I linked.  It takes your flags from the last 7 days.  If you have more than 10 and 25% have been declined, you are flagged banned.  The image you provided only shows the last 2 days of flags, so it is doesn't give a complete picture.  I'm only guessing here, but I do not believe your active flags factor into the equation at all, or if they do, they don't count against you.

Comment: @psubsee2003 that explain but don't fix it for me. So I'll never be able to flag SO posts again until a mod fix my flag list (with 19 being on hold?)

Comment: It only looks at flags from the last 7 days, so once you no longer meet the criteria, you'll be able to flag again.  This is designed to be a speed bump to slow you down so you try to focus on improving your flagging, not ban you completely (in fact that is why this was implemented because the old functionality was almost like a permanent ban

Comment: @psubsee2003 ok, but my flags that are on hold are most "this is dup" I don't have rep on SO to "close vote" yet, so I flag those. And "This is link only"

Comment: The flags aren't "on hold", they are active.  They could be handled at any time, which could also change the equation (depending how the existing formula treats active flags) and hence your ban status.  I'd count all of your handled flags from the last 10 days (ones that are not marked as active) and then count how many are declined.  If that comes to more than 10 total flags, and more than 25% declined, then that's your problem.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I added the counters. Please, take a look.

Comment: On the surface, it doesn't look like you are at 25% since 2/15 < 0.25, but depends on how the flags are counted. If disputed count as declined, then you are over 25%. We'll see what Shog says to my comment on his answer

Comment: Possibly vaguely related - [Don't let flag-to-close flags linger for months in flag purgatory](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203670/dont-let-flag-to-close-flags-linger-for-months-in-flag-purgatory)

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is bound to the size of the community. A lot of questions being posted means a big work for moderators. Which are not payed for they contribute.

For sure it's really important to avoid drawing moderator attention for the *wrong* reasons.

Also, as the comment are already saying, it's only about your recent flags.

Comment: So, basically I need to wait for 10 days before open any flag?