# Do flags to close expire like votes to close?

Tags: support, review, flags, vote-to-close

Votes to close are known to expire, for the reasons explained eg in answers to this question: [Why do close votes expire?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120896/why-do-close-votes-expire)

Does something like this happen to flags to close cast by users lacking [CV privileges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions)?

Side note - related question makes one feel that it's unlikely the case: [Don't let flag-to-close flags linger for months in flag purgatory](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203670/dont-let-flag-to-close-flags-linger-for-months-in-flag-pergatory)

---

<sub>I ask because per [recent changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/187008/165773) flags like that are no longer targeted to moderators only, but instead, go to same [review queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/review/info) as votes to close. This makes one wonder if the reasoning for votes expiration can now be applied to flags.</sub>

Comment: Yet someone at least went through and took care of my ancient flags. Now my oldest one is (only) two months and change old ([September 3rd](http://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/1933347)). So that's progress maybe?

Comment: @jmac this progress is most likely due to [meta effect](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204311/165773). As an example, after you posted here, I figured one or two of your flags from comments at SO and cast CVs, which resolved these. Also, note what Bill said [in comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203670/dont-let-flag-to-close-flags-linger-for-months-in-flag-pergatory#comment649651_203670): "I cleared a couple of your pending flags..."

Comment: I thought maybe (just maybe) a few moderators ran a query on old close vote flags over X age, and took care of them that way. The questions I had flagged seem to have been deleted for a large part, so I can't check up on them, but I'm thinking it may have been the acts of some conscientious mods. At least hoping it wasn't just my flags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently only canonical migration flags (obviously not custom-written migration flags) are automatically expired, and only when the question becomes ineligible for migration (they don't follow the normal expiration rules as a close vote would). Once expired, they are marked as "aged away."

As per [Shog's comment on another question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204327/when-are-moderator-flags-automatically-dismissed-as-aged-away-by-the-system#comment654972_204347):

> The majority of flag types in the system are not currently aged, including Recommend Close flags that do not involve migration.

Comment: thanks! would it make sense to establish expiration for close flags? if you think yes, I can convert my question from [meta-tag:support] to [meta-tag:feature-request] or open a new one. If not, your answer resolves my question in its current form

Comment: I don't see the need for another question. The feature-request you linked in your question would be a good place to just post an answer suggesting an alternative way of handling ancient close flags (aka, let them expire).

Comment: thanks! [there you go](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207182/165773) - "reposted as an answer" there