# Receiving chat notifications 5-10 seconds before the message that caused the notification?

Tags: bug, chat, ping

So here's the situation, I'm chatting away on The Bridge, and suddenly I receive a bunch of notifications indicating somebody just @pinged me:

[image]

However, as you can see, I've received the notifications but not the actual messages. In fact, chat stayed looking like this for another ~10 seconds before I suddenly received 6 messages at once.

Now, I know you're going to want to say latency, but I had already received the notification message stating somebody had @pinged me, so what gives?

Comment: Unicorns playing with chat...

Comment: There are two websockets. One for the notifications, one for the main  display. Don't ask me why or whether.

Comment: Gonna need more information about this to even *guess* at what's going on. What browser? What OS? Any firewall software / hardware involved? Are [websockets working properly?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172696/websocket-connection-failing-on-every-stackexchange-page) Is your browser pegging your CPU? How many chat rooms do you have open in tabs/windows when this happens? Are you playing 5 YouTube videos simultaneously in other windows?

Comment: Chrome 31/Windows 8.1/no software firewall (windows firewall disabled), router doing NAT/yes but I intermittantly get "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 409 (Conflict)" (not sure if that happened at the time, I only just looked at the dev console) - going to http://websocketstest.com/ results in a page full of ticks/no/8 rooms in 4 tabs/nothing else happening